# Laravel: SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost'

Tags: laravel, pdo

I just installed laravel and made a migration. But when i try to run it i get this error:

```
[PDOException]                                                               
  SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong? I think the Database.php file looks different than normal. Is this something new in the new Laravel?

My Database config:

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'LaraBlog'),
            'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
            'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'root'),
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
            'strict'    => false,
        ],
```

Hope someone can help me :)

Comment: Fix or grant access to db for needed user.

Comment: add your laravel version, have a look in the `.env` -file . Are you aware, that the data to you db-access reside in a .env-file? Is the username and password from the query correct? Or are these the defaults?

Comment: Updating my **.env** file and running `php artisan config:clear` fixed this for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to check out the ".env" file in your root directory. These values are taken first. Yours are just the defaults if there are none given in the .env file.

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql 
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=Your_Database_Name
DB_USERNAME=Your_UserName
DB_PASSWORD=Your_Password
```

Answer (score 25):

I tried to make changes to database.php file present within config folder it looks something like this

```
'default' => 'mysql',
....
...
'mysql' => [
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'sample'),
            'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
            'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
            'strict'    => false,
        ],
```

I am not using any VM, I am using my local machine, with the database user as root and password a null.

I have also changed my .env file and it looks something like this:

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=zLzPMzs5W4FNNuguTmbG8M0iFqhIVnsP

DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=sample
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=null

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
```

Even after doing all the changes when I try to register using the registration form that is shipped with laravel, I try to add a user to my database I get the following error

[image: laravel database connection error]

After doing all the changes I cleared the cache and loaded it again and it seems to work for me now!
if any one is also facing the same issue just run the following commands

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:cache
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. The two artisan command saved my day. Laravel sometime becomes nasty.

Comment: Worked for me as well.. Thnx !

Comment: Just recently started using Laravel 5.4 and was having same issue. This helped a lot, those commands.

Comment: I should note down those two lines. Worked like a charm.

php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:cache

Answer (score 4):

I figured it out :) Had to chance the .env file :)

Is there any changes in the schemaes?

Shouldn't this work:

```
public function up()
{
    // Create table with columns
    Schema::create('users', function($table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('username');
        $table->string(Hash::make('password'));
        $table->string('firstname');
        $table->string('lastname');
        $table->string('email')
        $table->string('role');
        $table->timestamps();
    }); 

}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    // Insert table to database
    Schema::drop('users');
}
```

Comment: Forgot ; after (email)

Answer (score 0):

Make changes in the database.php file in **config > local >database.php
rather than change config > database.php file.

hope it will work ;)

Answer (score 0):

practically when you are using localhost server like xampp, you create the database manually "homestead", such errors are due to missing database arguments. 100% percent working test it and see

hit your cmd and type in:

```
create database homestead;
```

Answer (score 0):

i got the same issue after creating laravel project. The authentication command run successfully.

```
 php artisan make:auth
```

But when i try to register or login i got the same error. I run the following command

```
    php artisan config:clear
```

then stopped laravel application and also my server. after restarting my laravel app and server everything was ok.

Answer (score 0):

Tried all the solutions here but no work for me

This Worked on the first try:

> If you are using the PHP's default web server (eg. `php artisan serve`) you need to restart your server after changing your `.env` file values.

I found this solution from here [laravel.io](https://laravel.io/forum/02-14-2015-sqlstatehy000-1045-access-denied-for-the-user-homesteadlocalhost-password-yes) (Read the solution of Byjml)