# Error in migrate it's error 1045

Tags: php, laravel, migrate

I have a problem when I write `PHP artisan migrate` it is error 1045 but I give my password in .env file tru.
Please help me fast.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel: SQLSTATE\[28000\] \[1045\] Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29345841/laravel-sqlstate28000-1045-access-denied-for-user-homesteadlocalhost)

Answer (score 0):

first sure you are enter true user and password
then sure your mysql port not changed
finaly edit AppServiceProvider.php file and add this:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

function boot()
{
Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
}
```

good luck